# Smooth CSS transform on hover with height:auto

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like a card to flip over on hover using CSS transform.

I have found the following to work:

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
  background: #343434;
  color: #fff;
}


/* flip speed goes here */

.flipper {
  transition: 0.4s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  max-height: 999px;
  position: relative;
}


/*  front pane, placed above back */

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
  <div class="flipper">
    <div class="front">
      <!-- front content -->

      <h3>Until 4 Oct 2015</h3>
      <h2>Tyrannosaurus - Meet the Family</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="back">
    <!-- back content -->

    <h3>In short</h3>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus - Meet the Family explores how these terrifying dinosaurs became the world's top predators with their massive skulls, powerful jaws, and bone-crunching teeth.</p>
    <a class="button" href="#">Find out more</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

However, when hovering over the card the animation stutters - the reason I think is because .card-container parent element is not adapting to the full height of the child divs.

It's also important that the height of the card is set to **:auto** as there will be cards of varying heights on the same page depending on the length of the text inside.

Thanks for your help.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvbjEQ

Comment: it looks ok, the white goes behind the green and black is turning correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the absolute position you are using with both `front` and `back` which make the height of parent element to be 0. Instead you can simply make only one element abosulte position and keep the other one relative.

You can simplify the code like this :

```css
body {
  background: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  padding: 20px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

/* entire container, keeps perspective */

.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  
}

.flip-container,
.front,
.back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* hide back of pane during swap */

.front,
.back {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  text-align: center;
}

.back {
  background: #343434;
  color: #fff;
}


/* flip speed goes here */

/*  front pane, placed above back */

.front {
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  position: relative;
}


/* back, initially hidden pane */

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}


/* flip the pane when hovered */

.flip-container:hover .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.flip-container:hover .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-container" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
    <div class="front">
      <!-- front content -->

      <h3>Until 4 Oct 2015</h3>
      <h2>Tyrannosaurus - Meet the Family</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="back">
    <!-- back content -->

    <h3>In short</h3>
    <p>Tyrannosaurus - Meet the Family explores how these terrifying dinosaurs became the world's top predators with their massive skulls, powerful jaws, and bone-crunching teeth.</p>
    <a class="button" href="#">Find out more</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```